# Detailed Description: Okay to give implementation suggestions and tips?

Tags: description, detailed-description

Is it okay to give implementation "suggestions", or do descriptions of embodiments need to be exacting? Could an answer please elaborate on why or why not by adding experience or anecdotes? My feeling is that the description should teach the reader how to build one or more of the embodiments, even with tips.

For example,

> As a possible implementation suggestion, a recommendation of 18 AWG wire is advised.

> As a recommendation for a possible implementation, a DC-DC buck converter may be employed to lower said voltage.

> It is advised to incorporate fuses where appropriate. A person skilled in the art will be able to place such fuses appropriately.

Could I add some preamble or "other remarks" to cover myself? For example:

> Throughout, implementation suggestions may be supplied to aid in construction of one or more embodiments of the disclosure. It must be noted that whenever supplied, such suggestions are not to be construed as a nomination for a dominant embodiment, nor a narrowing of the scope of the disclosure.

Answer (score 1):

The specific hints you mention are not necessary but probably won’t hurt. The boilerplate wording is fine and might help.